# find duplicate declared functions in c library (single files)

Tags: c, gcc, linker, embedded

I'm working on an embedded project and I am duplicating a sample project.
Not taking the linking order of the object files into account, I just put the `c` files in a random order in my `Makefile`.

Compiling and linking yields an `executable.elf` of `1.9Mb`.
No errors were generated but the executable didn't work.

After a long search with no solution I finally duplicated the project exactly, including the order of the `c` files (120 of them) and behold I got an `executable.elf` of `2.2Mb` and no errors. AND the executable worked.

Nothing changed in compile-options and/or linking-options. Just changed the order in which the `c` files are listed in the makefile, and therefore the order of the object files at link time.

I suspect that there are multiple duplicate function implementations with different bodies/sizes. My hypothesis is that link time the linker, with no memory of previous link actions, just picks the first one it encounters without raising an error.

However I would like to get a hold on this provided library (all single `c` files, no lib `*.a` file) and find the duplicate function implementations. So I know in which order I should provide the c files and more importantly, why.

Two questions:

1. Is the description above, indeed a potential cause of the issues?
2. Are there other possibilities?
3. How to find the duplicate function implementations?

Unfortunately, the code being compiled is proprietary and details cannot be shared at this time.

Compiler is:

```
 arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 5.4.1 20160919 (release) [ARM/embedded-5-branch revision 240496]
```

Target is:

```
 cortex-m3
```

Your help is appreciated.

--- EDIT ---

There are two files:

1. is the list with all the source code (source.mk):

   ```
    C_FILES_SRC  = $(SDK_DIR)/file001.c
    C_FILES_SRC += $(SDK_DIR)/file002.c
    C_FILES_SRC += $(SDK_DIR)/ .....
        |
    C_FILES_SRC += $(APPL_DIR)/file121.c
    C_FILES_SRC += $(APPL_DIR)/file122.c
   ```
2. is the `Makefile` (short version):

   ```
   include source.mk
   CFLAGS = xxxxx
   # create objects
   %.o: %.c
       $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF($(@:%.o=%.d) -o $@ -c $<

   # link it all together
   executable.elf
       $(GCC) $(MAIN_CFLAGS) $(LINK_SCRIPTS) -Xlinker --gc-sections $(LIBS_DIR) $(EXTRA_LINK_FLAGS) $(SPECS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
       $(SIZE) --format=berkeley $@
   ```

In the `Makefile` I change nothing. Only changed the order of files in source.mk

Comment: I know you said you can't post the code itself, but can you post an obfuscated equivalent of your `Makefile`?  Thanks!

As is, we don't even know what the structure of your `Makefile` is or what buildsystem you are using to generate it (if any).  This will likely make it harder to provide you a definitive answer.

Comment: You say 'My hypothesis is that … the linker … just picks the first one it encounters without raising an error'. That would be extremely unusual, and wrong. If there are two object files defining the same externally visible function, the linking should fail with a duplicate function error. The easiest way to simulate that is to add one object file to the list twice; the link should fail when you do. Have you checked the sizes of the object files?  Have you compared the `size` output for the two binaries?  Were the compilation options the same? Compiler versions?

Comment: I just added an arbitrary library `c` file to my application and compiled/linked it. So there are two identical object files with different locations. No errors from the linker.

Comment: Just added simple version of my `Makefiles` in original question.

Comment: My hypothesis is based on what I read [here](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~fsalvi/docs/gcc/www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_14.html)  On Unix-like systems, the traditional behavior of compilers and linkers is to search for external functions from left to right in the object files specified on the command line.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, create a *library* from your object files? A library, in contrast to a bunch of object files, does accept duplicate symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Only static libraries (.a or .lib) exhibit "first match resolution" such that link order was critical.  Since *all* object files are explicitly linked, you'd get a link error if there were duplicate symbols.  So only the order the the .a/.lib files are presented to the linker could have that effect.

Perhaps you have two different versions of a library and are linking both in a different order?

The GNU toolchain's binutils includes the [nm](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.27/binutils/nm.html#nm) tool for examining symbols in object and archive (library) files.

An alternative possibility is that the executable entry point is sensitive to link order on your platform; in which case it may just be the link order of crt0 (or other run-time start-up code).

Comment: After testing I think your **alternative possibility** is the one. Putting the file 'startup_AMRCM0.S' at the beginning of the list all goes well, putting 'startup_AMRCM0.S' as the last file in the list, linking goes wrong. I have check other projects I have done with the same `GCC` compiler toolchain and they all have the start-up code at the beginning of the file/object list, by accident :-) so I never encountered this problem before.

Comment: Would be nice to find confirmation about this behaviour in the [GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) documentation. If I find anything I'll report it here.

Comment: @Robert : The problem with a collection of tools from multiple projects is whose responsibility is it to document these things?  It is not perhaps an intrinsic issue with the GNU toolchain.  Cortex-M3 loads a stack pointer and start address from the reset vector - there are numerous ways of making sure these match up with the `_reset` symbol (or whatever) in the run-time start-up code;  it may be possible to force the location in the linker script rather then relying on default link order.  I recalled having this issue a long time ago with GNU which is why I mentioned it.